# How to Display Different Sidebar for Each Product category page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce plugin. I will try to add widget selection options add in product category page. These is possible or not?
Thanks in advance.

```
add_filter( 'avf_custom_sidebar', 'enfold_customization_custom_sidebar', 10, 1 );
function enfold_customization_custom_sidebar( $custom_sidebar ) {
     if ( is_product_category( 'rings' ) ) { $custom_sidebar = 'Ring Sidebar'; }
else { $custom_sidebar = 'Earring Sidebar'; }
     return $custom_sidebar;
}
```

but these code is not work. I have add two category rings and earrings and both category sidebar display different.